# How to test instance variable was instantiated in controller with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to check that a new action in my RESTful controller set up an instance variable of the required Object type. Seems pretty typical, but having trouble executing it

**Client Controller**

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
end
```

**Test**

```
describe "GET 'new'" do
  it "should be successful" do
    get 'new'
    response.should be_success
  end

  it "should create a new client" do
    get 'new'
    assigns(:client).should == Client.new
  end
end
```

**Results in...**

```
'ClientsController GET 'new' should create a new client' FAILED
  expected: #,
       got: # (using ==)
```

Which is probably because it's trying to compare 2 instances of active record, which differ. So, how do I check that the controller set up an instance variable that holds a new instance of the Client model.

Answer (score 37):

technicalpickles in #rspec helped me out...

```
assigns(:client).should be_kind_of(Client)
```

Comment: How about if Im working with a REST and I don't use "@" in the controllers? Is there a workaround? Thanks

Comment: For rails 5, use `expect(assigns(:client).to be_a(Client)`

Comment: What to do for something like @roles = UserRole.all

Answer (score 16):

You can use Rails' new_record? method to check if a given instance has been saved to the database already or not:

```
assigns(:client).should be_a(Client)
assigns(:client).should be_new_record
```

(You can't use assigns[:client] for historical reasons, according to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-four-hashes-of-the-apocalypse)

Comment: The link to "four-hashes-of-the-apocalypse" explains everything a Rails dev needs to know about the environment views receive from controllers!

Answer (score 15):

For that 2016 RSpec v3 syntax use:

```
expect(assigns(:client)).to be_a(Client)
```

Also, for others that may stop here because of the question title, here is how to test if an instance variable `@client` was set to anything

```
# in controller action
@client = Client.find_by(name: "John")

# spec assignment based on collection membership

expect(assigns.keys).to include('client')
```

See [@Attila Györffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660042/3319298) about why the assigns hash must be accessed with string keys.