# How to check if instance object inside controller has attribute set in rspec for REST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working with a REST approach with rails and I'm not using the notation assign "@user" inside the controllers.

Example of my controller:

```
def create
    user = User.new
    user.star = true
    user.save
    ...
end
```

For a classic rails app [this the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051373/how-to-test-instance-variable-was-instantiated-in-controller-with-rspec):

```
expect(assigns(:user).star).to be_present
```

But unlike the use of `@`, I need to access the `user`

How can I achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: The best approach would be to not test the controller. Put this in a service and test the service. Have the controller use the service. Then test everything is wired together correctly with an integration test.

Comment: @AlexPeachey Thanks. I'm kind of new in tests, but will I not step in this problem again? Could you guide me with some links to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're creating the user you could just load the last one created:

```
describe 'create action' do
  let(:user) { User.last }

  it 'sets star to true' do
    post :create, user: {}
    expect(user.star).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

Comment: Model.last!! Genius haha